# Authenticate an API call correctly with requests and sessions

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I want to call my own API in a custom view I wrote. Normally I use JWT authentication with my API calls. In this specific view though, I'd like to use a different authentication.

I want to enable logged in users to make a successful get call (without a token). Not logged in users should not be able to make that call. I tried this with Basic Authentication and Session Authentication but don't really get it tow work.

Here is my view that makes the API call:

```
def visualize_buildings(request, id):
    passed_id = id
    endpoint = 'linktomyendpoint' + str(passed_id)

    response = requests.get(endpoint)
    building_group_data = response.json()
    # print(building_group_data)

    if 'buildings' in building_group_data:
        building_data       = building_group_data['buildings']
        context = {'building' : building_data}
        return render(request, 'building_group_visualize_api.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Ups. We are sorry but no Building Group was found with that id")
```

Here my API view:

```
class BuildingGroupRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):

    authentication_classes = [JSONWebTokenAuthentication, 
 SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    serializer_class = BuildingGroupSerializer
    queryset = BuildingGroup.objects.all()
```

The view works with if I send a token in the headers. But how can I use Session Authentication with that? I tried getting username and password from the request and then pass it to the API call. But that doesn't work because I can't decode the password from the request (which makes sense). 
So I tried to follow this: `https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/` but I still can't authenticate my request.

Can anyone point me into the right direction? Help is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session ids are saved as a cookie on the user's device and they will be sent to the server as a header name `Cookie`. So if you want to use cookies instead of the JWT token then you should send your request with the session id as a cookie header.

This is the header that lets Django know your session-id when you visit the site directly:

```
Cookie: csrftoken=some-csrf-token; sessionid=your-session-id
```

Now to make your request contain something like that:

```
cookies = {'sessionid': 'your-session-id'}
response = requests.get(endpoint, cookies=cookies)
```

Note that Django might still through an error for csrf token based on your settings.

You can find your session-id on your browser. If you don't know where and how to access them, just google it. it's different based on the browser you use.

Comment: Navid, thanks a bunch my friend. I'll try this as soon as I get back to my compu and let you know how it went! Thanks! A question upfront though: Is there no need to create a session object then like explained here: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/ ?

Comment: No problem. Django doesn't have an API to create or set any session-id, it does it on login. so you have to use your own session id or create one manually.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I tried this now. Got my session key with ```session_id = request.session.session_key``` , saved that to a variable and passed it in my request as you recommended. Worked flawlessly. Thank you very much, really helped me out!